# Remove swatches only in layered navigation Magento 2.1.x

Tags: layered-navigation, swatches, magento-2.1.7

I enabled visual swatches for color attribute and they display correctly but I don't want them in layered navigation.
I tried to change code in `Magento_LayeredNavigation/templates/layer/view.phtml` without success.
Hope you can help me.

**Update**:
I forced it using this script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    require(['jquery'], function($){ 
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $(".swatch-attribute.swatch-layered.color .swatch-attribute-options a").each(function(){
                var label = $(this).attr('aria-label');
                $(this).text(label);    
            }); 
        }); 
    });

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Goto the `Stores ->  Products -> Edit Color attribute -> Storefront Properties`  and set `Use in Layered Navigation = No`

Comment: this will remove the attribute completely from the layered nav. I think the OP wants just the swatch removed.

Comment: Exactly, I want to remove swatches only. I need the attribute there.